How to securely store and retrieve sensitive data in a .NET Standard 2.0 cross-platform (Windows+Linux) library
I have .NET Framework 4.7.2 library to store and retrieve sensitive data (like tokens for our desktop apps communication) with help of CredentialManagement package on Windows. Now I need to make this library work both on Windows and Linux. I've retargeted it to .NET Standard 2.0 (to be able to consume it from both .NET Framework and .NET Core desktop apps) and used KdSoft.CredentialManagement package (since CredentialManagement.Standard package was unlisted from nuget.org). I determine operating system with RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform:
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    //Use CredentialManager
}
else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
    //What to use here?
}
else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

But I have no idea what library to use on Linux to achieve the same goal. What is the most common approach on that OS?
P. S. My library doesn't use any database. And I saw similar questions #1 and #2: they are about Windows-only approach and answers there (Data Protection API for Windows - ProtectData class) doesn`t support Windows Home and on non-NTFS.

You should be using that latest Core version so you can use OAUTH2 authentication.  Core was developed so you can run same app on Windows, MAC, and Linus without modifying the source code.  Core rewrote the libraries so they are independent of OS.  Using Net 4.7.2 probably requires code changes so you app will run on linux.

@jdweng What do you mean by latest Core version? My library targets .NET Standard 2.0 (to be able to consume it from both .NET Framework and .NET Core applications). Or what are you talking about?

Net 2.0 is the last version to supports Framework. Most people are using Core 6.0, 76.0, or 8.0 which will run on Windows, Linux, and Mac without any code changes.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#select-net-standard-version

@jdweng I intentionally target .NET Standard 2.0 in my library because part of our clients still use .NET Framework 4.7.2 (and they are not planning to change that in nearest future). I cannot just switch my library to .NET Core 6.0+.

Windows credentials will not work.  So I think you are going to have to use SSH.  See : https://www.luisllamas.es/en/ssh-net/

@jdweng Could you elaborate, please, how SSH.NET can help me: this library helps to connect to remote machines using the SSH protocol. But my question is about storing credentials on Linux (similar to Windows credentials store).

SSH allows you do login on a remote machine using a Username and Password (credentials).  The credentials are encrypted so they cannot be hacked during transmission.  OAUTH22 will allow credentials to work like windows.  But you are using Net 4.7.2 which doesn't support OAUTH2.  So 4.7.2 does support SSH login without credentials automatically being recognized.

I ended up with Devlooped.CredentialManager nuget (.Net Standard 2.0, MIT license) - a .NS20 port of a cross platform Git Credential Manager. It supports several credential stores - I use GPG/pass compatible files.
Another option could be Simple.CredentialsManager nuget (.Net Standard 2.1, Apache-2.0 license) but version at nuget.org is extremely outdated. It also has a pull request returning .Net Standard 2.0 target and another one with handy readme.md update but both are still not merged.
